# Bokeh: xwheel_pan and ywheel _pan tools not working

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm a bit new to Bokeh, and I've been struggling with getting the xwheel_pan tool to work. I've tried this. I can change the tools argument to [anything](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tools.html?highlight=pan#bokeh.models.tools.Scroll) except xwheel_pan and ywheel_pan for some reason. I'm using Bokeh version 1.4.0

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

p = figure(plot_width = 900, tools='xwheel_pan')
lines = [p.line(np.arange(10), np.random.random(10)) for i in range(3)]

show(p)
```

Comment: I just tried this exact code with Bokeh 1.4 and it ran exactly as expected, so you will need to be more specific and detailed about what is actually happening, and what you are actually expecting.

Comment: I was expecting to be able pan the window along the x axis by scrolling with my mouse. It might be important to note that I am using a standalone python file. When I try scrolling on my figure, it stays still. Even after I have selected the tool.

Comment: Scroll tools are not active by default, you would need to click the tool icon to turn the tool on. Otherwise, the answer below by @hyles_lineata shows how it can be configured to be active at start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, your code almost works, except I found that the xwheel_scroll isn't active by default-- you have to click the tool icon on the toolbar to turn it on, and then it works.

In the arguments to `figure`, right after you declare `tools`, specify the active scrolling tool, like this:

`p = figure(plot_width=900, tools='xwheel_pan', active_scroll='xwheel_pan')`

See if that does what you expect.